# regular expression to match comma-formatted numbers with decimals

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression:

```
^\$?(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$
```

however it is failing when i have an amount such as this: `41022095.6`

anything I am missing?

Comment: Also note that you won't match any number with just a single digit before the decimal point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression expects either no decimal point, or a decimal point followed by *two* decimal digits. It depends on what you want, but you could make your regex match your suggested input by doing this:

```
^\$?(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

I changed the `{2}` near the end to `{1,2}` to allow one or two decimal digits after the decimal point. I also changed the `.` to `\.` because a plain `.` in a regex means "match any character".

Comment: Doesn't the leading \$ also requires a dollar sign for the accepted input?

Answer (score 1):

doesn't the dot mean "[any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)", unless it's in brackets?

Answer (score 0):

This part: `"(.\d{2})?"` says that your number can optionally end in "dot followed by two digits", but it's optional. Since you don't have "dot followed by two digits" anywhere in your example and nothing else that allows a dot, it is not matched.

Also, ass duffymo pointed out, you probably want to escape the dot to make it match the full stop instead of any character.

Comment: should still match everything up to the dot.  and the dot doesn't match a dot.

Comment: Yes, everything up to the dot, but since the regex ends in "$" it doesn't actually match unless it matches the *whole string*. Also: A "." in a regex does actually match a "." in the target String (together with a lot of other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that last bit to (.\d{1,2})?.  Otherwise it will require 2 digits at the end.

Also, you might want to escape the '.'

Comment: or maybe (.\d{0,2})? in case you want a decimal followed by NO fractional part.